# how to Build external kernel module without kernel source tree

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I have a 3rd party SW package that compile both kernel modules and user space applications. Unfortunately, this 3rd party is very complex, and doesn't use Kbuild for building kernel modules (I tried without success).

I tried to build a simple driver with the lines below:

```
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -include /lib/modules/4.4.62-18.6-default/build/include/generated/autoconf.h -MD -MP   -Werror -O2 -I /usr/src/linux-4.4.62-18.6/include -I /src/include -DMODULE -c -o hello_dkm.o hello_dkm.c  
    $(LD) -o $(debug_target) $(LD_COMMON_FLAGS) -g $(debug_Objs)
```

I have got:

```
fatal error: /usr/src/linux-4.4.62-18.6/include/linux/thread_info.h:54:29: fatal error: asm/thread_info.h: No such file or directory
```

---

Appendix

- plateform: Altera Cyclone V SoC, ARM cortex A9 dual core
- Kernel: linux Altera 3.7.0
- host: Linux openSuse 42

PS: In my team's project plateform it is hard to use the classic compiling line using the kernel source tree:
    `$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think `c++` tag doesn't apply for this question.

Comment: For compile kernel module you need *some files from kernel build directory* (that is source directory after building the kernel) even if you don't use `kbuild` for your purposes. You need configuration options, as they are used (as macros) by Linux headers. You need versions of kernel core symbols from `Module.symvers` file. Describing whole build process without `kbuild` seems *too broad* for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

your immediate problem is that "asm/thread_info.h" is not in your `CPATH` and not specified in any of your `-I` parameters. you need to locate that file on your system and put its root into either the `CPATH` environment variable or an `-I` directive.

to make this clear, if you locate the file at `/usr/local/include/linux/asm/thread_info.h`, you must precede your `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` with `CPATH=/usr/local/include/linux`, or insert `-I /usr/local/include/linux` somewhere in the command line, perhaps right after `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.

there will likely be other problems, but that should get you to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

you can build kernel modules with (.ko files) Make file like,

Create Makefile with name "Makefile" then write this code into it;

```
obj-m += drivername.o
all:
make -c /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -c /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Then open terminal and write `make` command in the same directory which driver is placed. this will generate .o and .ko files of the driver .

with to insert the driver write `insmod`
the driver will be loaded to your kernel.

if I didnt understand wrong it would help to you

Comment: this requires kbuild though, and the OP stated he doesn't have that available in his build environment.